# IE7 window.location.href

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

I want to redirect a IE7 user, but `window.location.href` does not seen to work properly.

Any suggestion?

```
$('.navigation-next a').bind('click', function (a) {
    a.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href')
})
```

Worked with:

```
$('.navigation-next a').bind('click', function(a) {
   location.href = $(this).attr('href')
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: It should work fine - post your code

Comment: What do you mean with does not work?

Comment: Just a sanity check here. But you are adding a click event handler to an anchor element to go to the href attribute of that element? It does that by default with no JS required.

Comment: @JohnFx because it is disabled when start accomplish my others features.

Comment: I haven't seen your code, but that sounds like a serious kludge. Why not just enable the link when you are ready for it to be clicked and not try to overload the behavior with the exact same behavior as the default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `window.location.replace()` on IE7 and earlier.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redir(url){ window.location=url; }
</script>

<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redir(url){ window.location.replace(url); }
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

*This is why all web developers should drop support for IE until Microsoft fixes it!*

Comment: How to check it inside Javascript? `var ie7 = (document.all && !window.opera && window.XMLHttpRequest);` (return true/false)?

Comment: Just include the extra JS in your HTML using conditionals. It'll be way less hassle and is the standard mechanism for doing per-browser stuff.

Comment: While I upvoted (for answer), I'd guess the downvotes are due to the closing comment on web developers dropping IE support. First, thats impossible for most corporate web developers (trust me, i'd drop IE entirely if I could). Secondly, the only way MS can "fix" it is with new browsers, which they have released. Unfortunately, unlike Chrome / Firefox / etc, updating is neither intuitive or automatic in older versions of Windows, where IE7 lives.

Comment: Well this was 18 months ago. IE has gotten a lot better since then!