# Redirect to different pages on different dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to redirect user to different pages on different dates. I want to build this using jquery/javascript and needs to be compatible with IE7 and above. Here is what I have so far

Firstly the problem is **window.location.href seems to fail in IE7 and IE8**

Secondly this does not seem to work properly. can someone please provide me with a solution plus some example too...

```
 <script src="http://88ab3e84099be7e78755-9809173ac7d72ed2228bcf805441be5c.r76.cf2.rackcdn.com/32919/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>var a = new Date("01 23, 2013 19:30:00");
var b = new Date("01 30, 2014 19:29:59");

var c = new Date("01 30, 2014 19:30:00");
var d = new Date("02 06, 2014 19:29:59");

var e = new Date("02 06, 2014 19:30:00");
var f = new Date("02 13, 2014 19:29:59");

var g = new Date("02 13, 2014 19:30:00");
var h = new Date("02 20, 2014 19:29:59");

var i = new Date("02 20, 2014 19:30:00");
var j = new Date("02 27, 2014 19:29:59");

var k = new Date("02 27, 2014 19:30:00");
var l = new Date("03 06, 2014 19:29:59");

todayDate = new Date();

if (todayDate >= a && todayDate < b) {
    discovery_refresh = window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.replace = "http://www.google.com";
    }, 0);
}
if (todayDate >= c && todayDate < d) {
    discovery_refresh = window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.replace = "http://www.yahoo.com";
    }, 0);
}
if (todayDate >= e && todayDate < f) {
    discovery_refresh = window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = "http://www.smh.com.au";
    }, 0);
}
if (todayDate >= g && todayDate < h) {
    discovery_refresh = window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.replace = "http://www.gmail.com";
    }, 0);
}
if (todayDate >= i && todayDate < j) {
    discovery_refresh = window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.replace= "http://www.bbc.com";
    }, 0);
}
if (todayDate >= k && todayDate < l) {
    discovery_refresh = window.setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = "http://www.news.com.au";
    }, 0);
}</script>

I am still here
```

Comment: Possible error: you are missing `;` in the function beginning with the second `if`.

Comment: In IE7 you can override `window.location.href` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180276/ie7-window-location-href . But in IE8 `window.location.href` works perfectly

Comment: yeah as @Markus403 pointed , your missing semicolon at the end of  `window.location.href="....."`

Comment: Whether I use `window.location.href` or `window.location.replace`, it does not seem to work for IE8 or IE7

Comment: This is interesting. If I do this `var a = new Date("01 23, 2013 19:30:00");alert(a);` I get an alert of NaN. How come. I thought new Date... produces date

Comment: have a look here for the correct date format: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp)

Comment: Solved by chanting the date sytax to `new Date(2013,01,23,19,30,30,00);`

Comment: You could significantly improve the logic by splitting each time block with a single variable (rather than the start / end variables you currentl have)... and then use `if (a <= now && now < b) { }` and then `if (b <= now && now < c) { }` etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your date syntax is wrong -  change it to something like 
`new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)` and it will work.

Source: [w3schools on Date Object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp)